# Explain how DHT works with an example of a P2P network

Tags: p2p, dht

i have a basic idea about DHT and P2P. I need to explain how DHT is used in a P2P network with an example. Thank you

Comment: You should check wikipedia. If you have *specific* questions not covered by WP or its primary sources then you can ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are structured, and unstructured p2p overlays, basically this means, that structured networks have rules that dictate where objects stored are going to be located, and how the network topology will be organized, unstructured overlays don't.

DHTs are the most popular examples of structured, overlays what it basically does is dictate how queries should be routed (ie finding who has object x), and how they should be placed, using varying methods, ie chord has a ring topology and uses consistent hashing + finger table, kademlia uses xor and a tree topology.